# When to stop training a object detection model ( YOLOV5 )

Tags: python, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

Hi I have three metrics on validation, obj_loss, vls_loss and box_loss, which one I should look at when deciding the timing to stop the model training?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In theory all three should start increasing at the same time, in practice it is
difficult to achieve. I recommend that you see these issues on github.

[1]: <https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/5199

[2]: <https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/6731

Comment: Write answer in detail, for more clearance